# Sequence with $\mathbb N$ as set of limit points

Tags: sequences-and-series

A friend of mine challenged me to find a sequence such that the set of its limit points is exactly $\mathbb N$.

He has not found any, and neither have I.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \ldots$ I suppose you get the idea

Comment: you ommitted $0$ but that's fine. +1

Comment: I did this on purpose, to me $0$ is not natural, but that's just a question of one's personal taste ;)

Comment: Formalizing: $$a_n=n+1-\frac{k(k+1)}{2},$$with $$k=\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}\rfloor.$$

Comment: How did $\sqrt{8n+1}$ appear?

Comment: @Berci: from the positive solution of $k(k+1)/2=n$

Comment: If $U \subset \Bbb{R}$, then isn't a limit point of $U$ a point $x \in \Bbb{R}$ such that given any deleted neighborhood $N \subset \Bbb{R}$ around $x$, $N \cap U \neq \varnothing$? If so, then the answer above has no limit points; though it does have convergent subsequences.

Comment: @Tom my understanding (and definition) of limit point (valeur d'adhérence in French) is via subsequences.

Comment: @Tom: I supposed the OP was talking about limit points of a sequence (also called cluster points or accumulation points in Wikipedia), not limit points of a set.

Answer (score 2):

$0-\frac12,0-\frac13,1-\frac13,0-\frac14,1-\frac14,2-\frac14,...$ has the set of nonnegative integers as the set of limit points.